# Mongoose, limit each element of array result

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To find objects with array of ids we can do this:

```
var idsArray = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
 SomeObject.find({'chatroomId': { $in: idsArray}}).exec();
  .then(function(someObjects) {
    console.log(someObjects);
})
```

Is it possible to limit result for each member in array?
Not for whole result like this:

```
SomeObject.find({'chatroomId': { $in: idsArray}}).limit(3)
```

but for each element. Maybe something like this:

```
SomeObject.find({'chatroomId': { $in: idsArray.forEach.limit(3)}});
```

Comment: So you want only three of each ID?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes, only three of each.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in one query. I think you may need to specifically query for all IDs one-by-one.

Comment: got it. I already did this with bunch of queries, just curious if its possible to merge all of this into one query.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a document structure like :

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("591931855d0aad80c996eab2)",
    chatName : 'SchoolChat',
    chatrootId : ['id1', 'id2','id3','id4','id5']
}
```

You can use following query to get what you need :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind : '$chatrootId' },
    { $limit : 3}, 
    { $group : {
        _id : '$_id',
        chatName : { $first : '$chatName' },
        chatroomId : { $push : '$chatrootId' },
        } 
    }   
]);
```

It will give you :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("591931855d0aad80c996eab2"), 
    "chatName" : "SchoolChat", 
    "chatroomId" : [ 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'] 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mihir. I'll test this out when I get back to this.